# While applying ./configure command to install omnetpp, I am getting the message about not finding the C compiler in $PATH

Tags: installation, window, omnet++, configure

I am installing OMNeT++. While executing the `./configure` command on the mingwenv file I am getting the message:

> no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Kindly help

Comment: Welcome at SO! Could you write what version of OMNeT++ are you using as well as what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for.showing the ray of light towards solution 
I had already installed omnet pp 5.4.1 on my window 8.1. Every thing was fine . Due to some reason I deleted it . When I reinstalled  , I am facing this problem that means I am not able to execute ./ configure command

Comment: Make sure that the installation folder does not contain spaces.